# Pull client with the same transaction X times in a row

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to pull the last 4 transactions for each client, then only return clients where those 4 transactions all = 'EFT Active' below is the code I have so far that pulls the last 4 transactions

```
SELECT dt.Client_no, dt.SCode  
FROM (SELECT Client_no, SCode, Last_Mdt,                     
DENSE_RANK OVER (PARTITION BY client_no ORDER BY Last_Mdt DESC) AS Rank 
FROM Transactions)dt

WHERE dt.Rank <=4
```

I know this isn't proper but I need to add something like this.

```
GROUP BY client_no 
HAVING (SCode = 'EFT Active) = 4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if a client only has three transactions in the history table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` operator to filter out those clients for which there is at last 1 record that is not 'EFT Active'. In this way only clients with all records = 'EFT Active' will remain:

```
WITH xxx AS (
   SELECT dt.Client_no, dt.SCode  
   FROM (SELECT Client_no, SCode, Last_Mdt,                     
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY client_no ORDER BY Last_Mdt DESC) AS Rank 
   FROM Transactions)dt

   WHERE dt.Rank <=4
)
SELECT * FROM xxx x1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 'Anything' FROM xxx x2
   WHERE x1.Client_no = x2.Client_no
     AND ( x2.SCode <> 'EFT Active' OR x2.SCode IS NULL )
)
```

Comment: I'm thinking both solutions would have worked but this is the one that worked for me. Just in case anyone else is trying this don't forget the '()' after DENSE_RANK. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To get those 4 rows you need a more complex approach:

```
with cte1 AS 
 (
   SELECT Client_no, SCode, Last_Mdt,  
      -- to get the last 4 rows you better use ROW_NUMBER instead of DENSE_RANK
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_no ORDER BY Last_Mdt DESC) AS rn
   FROM Transactions
 )
, cte2 as
 (
   SELECT Client_no, SCode, Last_Mdt, 
      -- count of 'Active' rows
      SUM(CASE WHEN SCode = 'EFT Active' THEN 1 END) OVER () AS x
   FROM cte
   -- only the last 4 transactions
   WHERE dt.Rank <=4 
) 
SELECT *
FROM cte2 
-- only those with 'Active' only
WHERE x = 4
```